# syntax in C++ for member function returning a function pointer

Tags: c++

I have the following program which I'd like to get it fixed. Not sure how to make it syntactically correct.

```
class A{
    void f(){};
    void (A::*)()get_f(){return &A::f;}
};
```

Also, I would like eventually move the function definition outline like the following.

```
void A::(*)()A::get_f(){
    return &A::f;
}
```

What the correct syntax here too?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: "Use a typedef." --[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5)

Comment: @Ed: just abstraction to my current problem. :)

Comment: The actual question - how to *write* the declaration - has already been answered by others. Here a link that may be useful for practising how to *read* them. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/complex_declarations.aspx

Comment: Extra point for anybody that can write a function that returns &A::get_f. `typedef` is cheating, so is `decltype`.

Comment: @rodrigo: I think that would be: `void (A::* (A::*get_get_f())())() {return &A::get_f;}`, then if you want to call `f()` on an instance of `a`: `(a.*(a.*(a.get_get_f)())())();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
class A{
    void f(){};
    void (A::*get_f())() {return &A::f;}
};
```

and similarly:

```
void (A::* A::get_f())(){
    return &A::f;
}
```

[See it in action on ideone](http://ideone.com/A4fe6). Note that using it is just the same as with typedef (in the other answers).

BTW, for extra points and vomit (ha, ha):

```
void (A::* (A::* get_get_f())())();
```

Comment: It's actually `void (A::*get_f())() { return &A::f; }` but a typedef is a better way.

Comment: @bames53: what is the difference between what you wrote and jpalecek's answer?

Comment: @jpalecek: can you also please add how to use it in `main()` if I still don't want to use a typedef?

Comment: @Qiang Li: I believe it would be: `(a.*(a.get_f()))();`.

Comment: @Qiang Li: Well, if you were to store the pointer locally, you'd do `void (A::*ptr)() = a.get_f(); (a.*ptr)();`, so if you combine all of it, you get the above.

Comment: @QiangLi there was a difference, but the answer has been updated. Originally one of the parens was in the wrong place. Although I don't actually see that in the history. The definition I saw originally was: `void (A::*get_f)()() {return &A::f;}`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a typedef:

```
class A {
    typedef void (A::*AFn)();

    void f() { }

    AFn get_f(){ return &A::f; }
};
```

Comment: Can I do it not using a typedef? Just curious.

Comment: You can, but nobody sane would want to.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is a typedef:

```
class A
{
  typedef void (A::*funptr)();
  void f() {}
  funptr get_f() { return &A::f; }
};
```

If you insist on writing it directly, use

```
class A
{
  void f() {}
  void (A::*get_f())() { return &A::f; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use typedef, It just makes the syntax easier to understand.

In the following example, the function is defined outside of your class.

```
class A{
    typedef void (A::*p)();
    void f(){};
    p get_f();
};

A::p A::get_f() { return &A::f; }
```

You can define it inside the class the same way,

```
class A{
    typedef void (A::*p)();
    void f(){};
    p get_f() { return &A::f; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
public:
    typedef void(A::*mem_ptr)();
    void f(){};
    mem_ptr get_f();
};

A::mem_ptr A::get_f()
{return &A::f;}

int main() {
    A a;
    A::mem_ptr p = a.get_f();
    (a.*p)();
}
```

http://ideone.com/Q7G4s

Source: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.6